# Remove empty lines using Regex and AltSearch

Tags: regex, libreoffice

I'm trying to match any white-space or blank lines in this test file, using [AltSearch](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer) extension. For some reason, I can't match space between `bar bar` and line 4.

Here is test file. To post it to Stack Overflow, I changed spaces to periods and tabs to TABs. (When you will change it back for personal testing, note, there is TABTABTAB below line 3, it's easy to overlook).

```
line1

line2
..............TAB

line3
TABTABTAB

foo foo
bar bar



line4


TAB..............

line5

.................

line6
```

And here is 2 versions of my regex. Both works identically for me.

```
\p*^\s*\t*\p+
\p*^(\s||\t)*\p+
```

I know, batch script inside AltSearch will be more easy way (and I already have working batch). My interest is about don't using batch.

Also doesn't work. I don't understand, maybe this AltSearch is just buggy as hell?

```
(\p*^\s*\p+)||(\p*^\p*)
```

Comment: `^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+`

Comment: @0m3r Yeah, but it will not work in LO.

Comment: `^\s*$` with multiline flag should work.

Comment: How about `\p[\s\n]*\p` ? It should match any number of whitespace (tabs and linefeed included) between the end of a paragraph and the end of the next one.

Comment: @Aaron I just started testing, but in it's original form - no, it doesn't. Also I added link to extension.

Comment: @Tushar I just started testing, but it seems it doesn't work in LO. I will test more. Also I added link to extension.

Comment: Got back at home and testing on a computer with LO installed. I haven't given up yet, but this extension... isn't the best I ever used (so far it has failed to match `^`  or `$` alone while it matches `^$` very well and has gotten into infinite loops twice)

Comment: Still searching for something better but you can at least make it work in two steps : 1) search for `\p[\s\n]+`, replace by the empty string ; 2) search for `\p{2,}`, replace by `\p`

Comment: Alright I give up now. Those `\p` are weird and clearly badly implemented in the extension, which will happily match `\p`, but fails to match `[\p]`. This wouldn't be a problem if `^` and `$` were correctly implemented, but as commented above they're not either. Sorry, hope the 2-step solution is fine or you can use another tool. If you're looking that way, I suggest XQuery or a specialized OpenDocument parser to work on the persisted XML files.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, there are some 2-steps solutions, they are quite easy. I'm very appreciated for information about XQuery. Seems to be very interesting. Extension is far from being predictable, I agree. It would be great to have some another one for working with regexs.

Comment: For XQuery, the idea is to work on the XML files that constitute an OpenDocument file (this works with `.docx` too ; for both extensions the file actually is a zip file which contains xml files). In your case you'd need to apply `delete //text:p[not(text())]` to the `content.xml`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150657/discussion-between-aaron-and-john-c-j).

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex

```
^$
```

Make sure you check the "Regular expressions" checkbox after expanding "Other Options" section.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the screenshot from the [Help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions) in LibreOffice

[image: Help]

Ideally, `^\s*$` should work as I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384663/remove-empty-lines-using-regex-and-altsearch#comment77801529_45384663), it's strange it's not working in LO.